# how to hide message from pander()?

Tags: r, pander

I'm a knitr user.

I would like to hide message
 "Table: Table continues below"
 from pander() .

Would you let me know what option works?

Thank you.

below is toy sample.

```
data <- matrix(c(1:100),nrow=1)
panderOptions("table.split.table", 100)
pander(as.data.frame(data))
```

Answer (score 6):

There are three [options](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#general-options) to override the default caption below tables. E.g.:

```
> panderOptions('table.continues', '')
> pander(as.data.frame(data))

--------------------------------------------------------------
 V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6   V7   V8   V9   V10   V11   V12 
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----- ----- -----
 1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10    11    12  
--------------------------------------------------------------


-----------------------------------------------------------------
 V13   V14   V15   V16   V17   V18   V19   V20   V21   V22   V23 
----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----
 13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20    21    22    23  
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```